# Matching Serial to OS Edition

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

Is there a way to determine from a serial Key which build/version it belongs to?

The previous admin provided a list of keys, but no indication of what OS they are for.

Specifically Win Vista and Win 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/516581/determine-which-software-product-a-microsoft-product-key-activates

> Unfortunately there isn’t. The product key sequence is according to a
>   mathematical algorithm. The product key is a partially random,
>   25-character alphanumeric code, specifically designed to defeat
>   against keygens and leaked serial numbers. The code has three (known)
>   components:
>
> ```
> An actual serial number
> Verification data (using modular math)
> A checksum (CRC) for typos
> ```
>
> [- Fergus](https://superuser.com/users/29347/fergus)

EDIT:  However, I did stumble across this.  Looks like what you are after, but I've never used it:

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/20816-The-Ultimate-PID-Checker

[image]

> The Ultimate PID Checker allows you to calculate the Product ID of
>   given product key. Key validity will be checked also. The unique
>   feature is reading keys from file and saving log. Performance of PID
>   generation is checked too - time spent on generating will be printed
>   under the result.
>
> Features:
>
> ```
> Generating PID from typed key/input
> ```
>
> ✔ for Windows 8/Server 2012 ✔ for Windows 7/Server 20008 R2 ✔ for
>   Windows Vista/Server 2008 ✔ for Windows XP/Server 2003 ✔ for Office
>   2010 and 2013 ✔ for current system ✔ for all builds >= 6.0.5365.8

Comment: To be completely accurate, there isn't a way to do it that's been made **public**.  Obviously, there's formula to determine which keys go to which edition, because Windows is able to tell you when your key doesn't match your edition.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - true.  The correct answer is "contact Microsoft licensing support"...or the real world answer is that the OP now has a set of janitor's keys...when he comes to a lock try each key until one opens the door. :)